# How to prove that this sequence does not converge to $0$?

Tags: limits

I'm trying to prove that the sequence $a_n=\sum_{m=1}^{M}e^{in\omega_m}$
not converges to 0.

I tried this:
$$|\sum_{l=1}^{M}e^{i\omega_{l}n}|^{2}=\sum_{l=1}^{M}e^{i\omega_{l}n}\sum_{m=1}^{M}e^{-i\omega_{m}n}
= M+2\sum_{l\neq m}cos\left(\left(\omega_{l}-\omega_{m}\right)n\right)$$
But I don't knew how to proceed from here.

Comment: So what is the mean value of $|a_k|^2$ ? And what is $\sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|^2$ ?

Comment: $|a_n|^2=|\sum_{m=1}^{M}e^{i\omega_m n}|^2$

Comment: Yes, so what is $\sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|^2$ and what is the mean value of $|a_k|^2$ ?

Comment: I don't knew what is $\sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|^2$?  it going somewhere?

Comment: If $\omega/2\pi \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ then the mean value of $b_n = \cos(\omega n)$ is $0$ (show it). Thus the mean value of $M+2\sum_{l\neq m}cos\left(\left(\omega_{l}-\omega_{m}\right)n\right)$ is ... ?

Comment: what if ? $\omega/2\pi \in \mathbb{Z}$ I can't figure how to handle this. thank u for your help.

Comment: What is $\omega_m$ ?

Comment: It can be any real number I think.actually I have already ask the same question the teacher assistant but didn't get an answer yet.

Comment: This is not a sequence, this is a series.